# Currency Mask JavaScript don't work

Tags: javascript, laravel

I trying to use a currency mask in my laravel application, for example, I have a Input to get value from my orders, and I need to that be format in BRL (Brazilian Currency).

**My Input**

```
<div class="input-group">
 <span class="input-group-addon">R$</span>
 <input type="number" class="form-control" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)" id="valor" name="valor" pattern="[0-9]*">
```

**My Script**

```
<script>
$(function(){
  $('#valor').inputmask("numeric", {
        radixPoint: ".",
        groupSeparator: ",",
        digits: 1,
        autoGroup: true,
        prefix: '$', //No Space, this will truncate the first character
        rightAlign: false,
        oncleared: function () { self.Value(''); }
    });
});
</script>
```

**Input**
[image]

Any suggestion? I read some examples in StackOverflow but I keep not understand.

Comment: So what is your problem exactly?

Comment: I edited, my Input dont get the currency mask